# How to get the second lowest value excluding zero and ignoring the duplicates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to get the second lowest UNIQUE value excluding the zero and excluding any duplicate values.

This is a sample of my data:

```
0 
1 
1 
3 
2 
4 
5
```

The value that I need is 2

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Your proposed edit radically changes the question, which isn't really fair to the several people who have already invested time answering this version.  Since the revision is so different, it's really a different question.  Please post that as a new question rather than invalidating the current answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using support cells, this way it's easier to see the logic, however you can of course combine everything into one formula.

[image]

- `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,0)` - count number of cells containing `0`
- `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,SMALL(A1:A7,D1+1))` - count the number of cells containing the smallest value (excluding `0`)
- `=SMALL(A1:A7,D1+D2+1)` - the second smallest value

The big formula would look like this:
`=SMALL(A1:A7,COUNTIF(A1:A7,0)+COUNTIF(A1:A7,SMALL(A1:A7,COUNTIF(A1:A7,0)+1))+1)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to do, but here is a way:
Using this screen shot as example (I took your example but used 3 for the second lowest..)

Assuming you have zeros all the time otherwise a quick way is to add a zero... or add some more test..
[image: Excel screen shot]

1. order your column with the numbers from A->Z (from lowest value to highest)
2. add a column to the left of it with the following code
   `=IF(F7>F6;1;0)+E6`
3. in a cell look for the second value with a vlookup
   `=VLOOKUP(2;E6:F13;2;TRUE)`

you add the column to the left of the data column because you need the lookup

You could also add a test directly on the values obtained, IF 2 then return the value and filter the column for that value or do a sum of the column in a cell (as there would be only one value it would return the value)

Hope this help

ps: you might need to use comas instead of ";" in the formula..

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((COUNTIF(A2:A8,A2:A8)=1)*A2:A8)),2),MAX(A2:A8))
```