# How to get the second lowest unique value if more than 1 value available excluding zero and treating duplicate value as 1 value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would to get the second lowest unique rating value from an array of 5 rating values if the values are different. Zero should be excluded. Duplicate values should be treated as 1 value. If the value in that array are the same, it should return that value without checking for second lowest unique value. If all the values are zero, it should return zero

[image: Sample Data_Ratings]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the second lowest value excluding zero and ignoring the duplicates in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1292731/how-to-get-the-second-lowest-value-excluding-zero-and-ignoring-the-duplicates-in)

Comment: The previous question only cater for certain scenario. Here I also want to handle if I have an array but the value all the same, so I want to return that value. I did amended my previous question to include my other conditions but I was suggested to post a new question as the older question already answered

Comment: @PeterH, this is not a duplicate of the other question.  It is a different scenario and the answers on the other question do not apply.

Comment: Yes, it's not a duplicate, however it'd be fair to refer to your previous question, show what you have and explain what else you still need.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in column **A** like:

[image]

In some cell, say **D1** enter the **array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$20>0,$A$1:$A$20))
```

In **D2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IF(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$20>D1,$A$1:$A$20))<$D$1,"",MIN(IF($A$1:$A$20>D1,$A$1:$A$20)))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

-The smallest value is in **D1**.
-The second smallest value is in **D2**.
-The third smallest value is in **D3**, etc.
-Zeros and blanks are ignored.
-Duplicates are removed.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: hi @Gary's Student, thanks for the solution. Is it possible to combine into 1 formula?

Comment: @Wan ...............perhaps...............tomorrow I will try....................